# Redirecting or using a handler inside a handler

Tags: go, router, gorilla, mux

Hi I am using go and gorilla-mux. I have a route handler that processes the request and I want to use another handler based on what happened with the request processing.

E.g. my main route at `/file/{file}` processes the content type and then goes to one of the following routes to then return the final response (I would need to pass the query/params info from this first handler to the second one):

`/video/{video}`
`/image/{image}`

Not sure where to start.

Alternatives are to put all of both handler code into the one handler, or to do this processing in my frontend which I'd prefer not to do.

Comment: Hi, you can name your route and use [router.Get](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.Get) from where you can get URL and redirect to correct path.

Comment: Hi eventually figured it out thanks. I was under the impression that route names were global. Had to create another router and copied over the HandleFuncs inside my handler. And then redirect.